# Viewport rendered with some objects display in solid mode

Tags: 3d-view

I am trying to find out if it is possible to display some objects in object mode when we are in rendered display mode.

I have created a studio spot with settings on viewport display, and i want keep the color (viewport display material) when i am on rendered display mode.

[image]

I can't use emission material for it because they will influate lighting of my scene.

Anyone have a solution, or some other idea?

Thx community !

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Emission Shader, but you need to prevent it from contributing to the lighting : in Object Properties / Visibility / Ray Visibility, uncheck everything except "Camera".

Comment: Oh sure ! I don't know why I didn't think about it... Thx !
But when i set my lighting settings in rendered viewport, it may have an effect :(